# Converting 10+GB data to ragged tensor

Tags: python, pandas, performance, tensorflow, time

I have a Pandas dataframe which is 13.4GB large. Considering it is a multi-index dataframe of which the first level varies in length, I would like to convert it to a ragged tensor. Here is how I do it:

```
def convert(df):
    X = df.groupby(level=0).apply(tf.convert_to_tensor)
    X = X.tolist()
    X = tf.ragged.stack(X)
    return X
```

However, due to the enormous size of the data, this process has become absolutely intractable.

I have found out the following:

- By far most of the time is being spent in the line "X = tf.ragged.stack(X)"
- tf.ragged.constant or even tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths are not faster.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is `X1` in this case?

Comment: @NoobVB, that should have been "X". It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I thought I had found was wrong; Using the factory functions such as `tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths` is tremendously faster, especially on large datasets. I think that's [because these functions require you to manually encode the data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#raggedtensor_encoding), whereas using `tf.ragged.constant` forces Tensorflow to calculate the encoding. Also, [they are implemented in C instead of in Python.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47853#issuecomment-806985381) However, be sure to set the argument `validate` to `False`, because the difference in time is enormous.